# need to repeat the subject in a coordinate clause?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, subjects, repetition

I'm editing a text and so far the sentence I'm working on looks like this:

> They are the ones we wanted to pay tribute to, and remind people what they protested against.

The subject of "remind" is "we" ... is this clear? And also, is the sentence correct?

I wonder if I need to repeat the subject: "and we wanted to remind people..."

Comment: You are wise to recognize you're not done editing yet. But the problem I see has less to do with elision of the subject than with confusion among the groups referred to by "the ones," "people," and "they."

Answer (score 1):

No. The comma directs to the reading

- They are the ones we wanted to pay tribute to, and *they* remind people what they protested against.

..............

Merely dropping the comma leads to what is probably a zeugma; better grammatically would be

- They are the ones we wanted to pay tribute to and the ones we wanted to remind people what they protested against.

But this is almost certainly not the intended meaning.

..............

Dropping the comma and adjusting the grammar allows the correct (resultative) reading:

- They are the ones we wanted to pay tribute to and in so doing remind people what they protested against.

Comment: Thank you Edwin Ashworth.... so in other words it is the cleft sentence as the beginning that confuses the reader as to what the subject of the second clause is, right?

Comment: I'd say rather that the original here is not formed according to the usual conventions, and this is what confuses. This often happens with (attempted) complicated sentences.

Comment: The original posted English was a translation, and I still had the German original very much in mind. I'm looking the place to choose your answer as "the winning answer"  Until I find it: many thanks again!